# Pass ADAL Token to authenticate to CRM Online - Web Application

Tags: .net, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I've been searching with Zero luck on this so far. I have a custom web application(.Net Forms) that I use ADAL to authenticate against our Azure B2B & B2C tenants based on a users domain. Our Dynamics CRM 365 is using the same Azure tenants. When a user logs into my site, I present them with a profile page. On this page is a link to our CRM portal. When they click on this link it opens another tab to our CRM.

My question, how would I go about avoiding needing the user to log in yet again? Our company has 10 Legacy web applications that I need to implement this on. I use ADAL to gather the login token outside of the standard way Microsoft would want you to as there has not been time allotted to re-architect our authorization setup to use the windows pop-up to login in. <- this isn't an option.

Is there a way to go about this?
I basically used this sample to gather the token
https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/29/authenticating-to-azure-ad-non-interactively/

Answer (score 0):

[ADAL token caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/token-cache) might help with what you're looking to do.

I first experimented with it using this [ToDo List sample solution](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect) which demonstrates a SQL-based token cache.

We have since switched to using Azure Table for our token cache, based on [this article](https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2016/12/using-azure-table-storage-as-adal-token-cache/).

Comment: maybe im missing something, I have that sample as well as others and they all push you to the microsoft login, which in turn does it's magic and adds the token to whatever mechanism it uses prior to returning back to the application. I did a code break AuthenticationResult. Prior to me typing in my data @MS my other tab (CRM) still was showing I needed to log in. The second I typed in my password and it hit my breakpoint back in my to do list app; I refreshed my CRM page and I was logged in.